# Which malts/hops (and how much) should I keep on hand for maximum flexibility?

Tags: hops, malt

Which varieties (and how much) of malts and hops should I keep on hand **to be able to brew the greatest variety of beers without having to go to my LHBS**?

For clarity, this is for brewing five gallon all-grain batches. Until use, the grain would be unmilled and stored in airtight containers and the hops would be vacuum sealed and stored in a freezer. The question about malts refers mostly to what selection of malts not including pale, 2-row, 6-row, and Pilsener would best supplement an existing inventory of those four base malts.

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on how long you plan on keeping them. Hops are something that you would want fresh, so keeping them on hand is not probably not a good idea. As far as malts - are you talking about doing all-grain brewing or extract?

Comment: Probably the only thing you (arguably) *always* need is Pale Malt. Everything else will vary by recipe. There are even some beers that don't use that at all, but it's probably the most commonly used malt (or extract).

Comment: I think we'd need to know the most common styles you choose to brew in order to answer this question.

Comment: @Graham The most common styles I would choose to brew are what I would have the grain and hops for; my question was what malts and hops should I have on hand in case a wild hair and an open day present themselves.

Comment: You've a "chicken and egg" problem then. The styles you like should determine what you keep on hand, not the other way around. In other words, if you only keep Noble hops on hand, you can't spontaneously brew American IPAs. If you don't have roasted barely or black patent, then stouts and porters are out. Unless you narrow down the styles, then you would need pretty much a small homebrew shop inventory on hand at all times in order to be able to spontaneously brew all styles with "maximum flexibility."

Comment: @Graham Consider how much can be done with an inventory 2-row, Maris Otter, Crystal 60L and debittered black malt; then throw in EKGs, Tettnanger, Saaz, and any dual-purpose New World hop. I'm not trying to win the NHC, just making good beer on a moment's notice.

Comment: @tacotuesday it seems like you've basically answered your own question there.

Comment: @tacotuesday Well with that mix you won't be able to make classic German lagers, wheat beers, porters, stouts, dark browns, etc. But regardless, I think your question is not particularly well suited for the Stack Exchange network, where the focus is on questions with specific, correct answers. I'd suggest posting on a forum like Homebrewtalk.com to solicit some cool recipe ideas and whatnot.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs Yes, I've realized that the ultimate reference to what I'm trying to do is my copy of Markowski's _Farmhouse Ales_. I've been looking for a graceful way to close this question, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@graham is correct. It is rather a massivly open question unless you specify what kind of beers you generally like to make.

e.g I brew English style ales and I can fashion a huge variety of beers from just: Maris Otter Pale Ale malt, Crystal malt & Chocolate malt and Fuggles, Goldings, Challenger & Northern Brewer hops. Yesterday for example I did a Whiteshield IPA, a Wadworth 6X and a Timothy Taylor Best Bitter using combos of the above.

But you may hate English Ale, so difficult to assist you unless you spill the beans a bit more ;)

Cheers!

Comment: Your second paragraph was exactly the sort of answer I had intended with my question, but style guidelines seemed to restrict the responses rather than encourage creativity.